# How to scrape specific data after login into the page using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xpath

I've been trying to get a specific data from a web page I login and plot it on a spreadsheet, but I got stuck at the beginning.
This is the code I'm looking at right now:

```
function login(){  
  var payload =
   {
     "Usuario" : "XXXXX",
     "Senha" : "XXXXX",
   };// The actual values of the post variables (like user_session[email]) depends on the site so u need to get it either from the html of the login page or using the developer tools I mentioned.
  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false
   };
   
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://ovoonline.com.br/" , options).getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var preco = json["???"]
  return preco;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to get:
**[image: strong text]**

This is its xpath:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

Here is the partial resulting log I get:

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
...
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="slideshow.js"></SCRIPT>
<script src="flash.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function abrir(pagina,largura,altura) {

//pega a resolução do visitante
w = screen.width;
h = screen.height;

//divide a resolução por 2, obtendo o centro do monitor
meio_w = w/2;
meio_h = h/2;


</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="778" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="778"><table width="778" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="8" valign="top"><img src="images/a.gif" width="8" height="106" /></td>
        <td width="763" valign="middle" align="left"><table border="0" width="763" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr> 
                <td width="156" height="54" bgcolor="#FFC631"><img src="images/d.jpg" width="156" height="54" border="0" usemap="Map100" /></td>
                <td width="171" height="54" valign="top" background="images/e.jpg"><form action="auth.php" method="post">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">                     
                      <tr> 
                        <td colspan="3" align="center"><b>AREA DO ASSINANTE</b></td>
                      </tr>
                      <input name="ip" type="hidden" value="XX.XXX.XXX.XXX">
                      <tr> 
                        <td colspan="3" height="23" valign="middle">Usuario<input type="text" size="5" name="login">Senha<input type="password" size="4" name="senha"><input name="image" type="image" src="images/botoes/ok.gif" align="absmiddle" width="29" height="18" /></td>
                      </tr>
                                          </table>
```

Appreciate your time!

Comment: Why  are you trying to use JSON.parse() ? ... It's not JSON at all.  It's just an html string.  You might try regex.  Personally, I'd use a chrome snippet and write my output to the console and paste it into the spreadsheet.

Comment: @AntonioSantos Can you provide a log of the value of `content`? Being able to see the data structure will make it easier for others to assist.

Comment: Hi @Russ! Just did it! I tried compacting it a bit, sso Stackoverflow allows this amount of code... Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Cooper! Thanks for your comment. I started trying to get it using xml and/or regex, but I realized I'll have to study these approaches...

Comment: The nice thing about doing it with a snippet is that the DOM is live so CSS selectors are live as well.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the data from the table, use a `DOMParser` and pass the argument `text/html` to it, so you can  traverse through the HTML with `document.querySelector`

So this code:

```
var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://ovoonline.com.br/" , options).getContentText();

var json = JSON.parse(content);
var preco = json["???"]
return preco;
```

Should become: (In this example, I will fetch the value of AREA DO ASSINANTE)

```
var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://ovoonline.com.br/" , options).getContentText();

// initaize instance of DomParser
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");

// now latch onto the tr element that you're looking for with querySelector
var preco= doc.querySelectorAll('td[colspan="3"]')[0].innerText; // => Logs AREA DO ASSINANTE
return preco;
```

For your specific value, pass the td element value to `querySelectorAll` along with the attribute the element has, and figure out it's index in the DOM. You can then access the `.innerText` property of that element to fetch it's value, and store it under the `preco` variable.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I get a DOMParser is not defined, though. I've been looking for a fix, but there isn't much online...I'm using Google Apps Script and I'm not sure it supports DOMParser...

Comment: Hi @AntonioSantos Try substituting the doc var with `var doc = XmlService.parse(content)`

Comment: Well...This is how this looks now:  
` var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://ovoonline.com.br/" , options).getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(content);
  var preco = doc.querySelectorAll('td[colspan="2"]');`
but this is giving me an error, saying urlfetch has been invoked too many times. Thanks a lot for your patience!